# metodo de busqueda de datos

Tags: java

Este es mi codigo y necesito crear un metodo de busqueda que al ingresar el nombre del libro me muestre tambien su naturalidad y su autor quien me ayuda por favor.

esto es lo que llevo

```
package libro;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Libro {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
        proceso l;
        l = new proceso();

        int i=0,n;
        System.out.println("Cuántos libros desea ingresar:");
        n=sc.nextInt();
        while(i<n){
        l.libros();
        l.nombreA();
        l.naturalidad();
        i=i+1;
        }
    }

}


public class proceso{

Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     String libros[],naturalidad[],nombreA[];
     int i=0;
     public void libros()
     {  
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del libro:");
        libros[i]=sc.nextLine();
     }

     public void nombreA()
     {
         System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del autor:");
         nombreA[i]=sc.nextLine();
     }

     public void naturalidad ()
     {
         System.out.println("Ingrese la naturalidad del libro:");
         naturalidad[i]=sc.nextLine();
     }


}
```

Comment: Yo crearia una clase Libro que tenga 3 propiedades, el nombre del libro, el nombre del autor y la "Naturailadad". Luego tendria un constructor que me creara un Libro por cada 3 input del usuario. Los guardaria en un Lista y asi luego podrias buscar por el.

Comment: podrias mostrarme el codigo ?

Comment: Poder, podria pero seria emplear mi tiempo en hacer tu tarea, si tienes dudas mas concretas (como se declara una clase, como se crea un constructor, como se crea una Lista) te puedo ayudar. Pero si hago tu tarea no aprenderas nada.

Comment: lo que no se crear es el metodo que me busque simultaneamente el autor y la naturalidad deacuerdo al nombre que el usuario dijite,igual muchas gracias

Comment: El metodo es facil.  El nombre, el autor y la naturalidad tienen el mismo indice en sus respectivos arrays.  Solo tienes que buscar el indice del libro que buscas y automaticamente tendras el autor y la naturalidad.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes hacer, es crear una clase libro, que aloje todos los atributos correspondientes (nombre, autor y naturalidad)

### Libro:

```
public class Libro {

    String nombre, autor, naturalidad;

    public Libro() {
    }

    public Libro(String nombre, String autor, String naturalidad) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.naturalidad = naturalidad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public String getNaturalidad() {
        return naturalidad;
    }

    public void setNaturalidad(String naturalidad) {
        this.naturalidad = naturalidad;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Libro [nombre=" + nombre + ", autor=" + autor + ", naturalidad=" + naturalidad + "]";
    }

}
```

Luego, puedes implementar un flujo para agregar libros, y crear un método para buscar por nombre e imprimir los datos (con el método toString sobrecargado anteriormente):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Proceso {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Libro> listaLibros = new ArrayList<Libro>();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Cuántos libros desea ingresar:");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sc.nextLine();
            Libro lib = new Libro();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del libro:");
            lib.setNombre(sc.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del autor:");
            lib.setAutor(sc.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Ingrese la naturalidad del libro:");
            lib.setNaturalidad(sc.nextLine());

            listaLibros.add(lib);
        }

        System.out.println("Ingrese nombre libro a buscar: ");

        Libro buscado = findByName(sc.nextLine(), listaLibros);

        if (buscado == null) {
            System.out.println("Libro no encontrado");
        } else {
            System.out.println(buscado.toString());
        }

    }

    public static Libro findByName(String nombreLibro, ArrayList<Libro> listaLibros) {
        for (Libro libro : listaLibros) {
            if (libro.getNombre().equals(nombreLibro)) {
                return libro;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

### Ejemplos de ejecución:

```
Cuántos libros desea ingresar:
1
Ingrese el nombre del libro:
1
Ingrese el nombre del autor:
2
Ingrese la naturalidad del libro:
3
Ingrese nombre libro a buscar: 
2
Libro no encontrado
```

---

```
Cuántos libros desea ingresar:
1
Ingrese el nombre del libro:
1
Ingrese el nombre del autor:
2
Ingrese la naturalidad del libro:
3
Ingrese nombre libro a buscar: 
1
Libro [nombre=1, autor=2, naturalidad=3]
```